# Windows Server 2012 video driver issue with Radeon 6770

Tags: windows-server-2012, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I'm missing several options in Catalyst Control Center, clicking detect displays causes CCC to hang. Under the Information tab in Catalyst Control Center under Hardware it says, Device ID, Graphics Bus, Maximum Bus setting, Memory size, Memory type, Core clock in MHz and Memory clock in MHz, are all "Not Available".

I get none of these problems in Windows Vista Ultimate 64-bit/Windows 7 Pro 64-bit/Windows 8 Pro 64-bit. (Yes, my particular build has experienced all these operating systems.)

I'm using 13.1 drivers, and I've tried the 12.x drivers.

This is a fresh install of Windows Server 2012

Specifications:

- Fx-8350
- 8GB G.Skill Sniper memory
- 1TB WD Black
- Asus M5A97 R2.0 (970 chipset) motherboard
- Diablotek 675W UL power supply.

Comment: have you tried running the CCC as root?

Comment: How would I do that? I think CCC is the problem myself. 

The install log shows the missing information.

Comment: find the CCC.exe in  your programs then right click and do "run as administrator"

Comment: Running as Administrator has done nothing. earlier I even even made sure to install by right clicking and choosing "Run as Administrator"

Comment: This sounds like a pure driver problem.  The solution would be to report it to AMD and hope its fixed.  You really don't need CCC nor the AMD drivers the generic display drivers are good enough on Windows Server 20012.

Answer (score 1):

Which AMD graphics products are supported on Windows Server® operating systems?

http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/34

The AMD Radeon™​ Graphics series are not supported under Windows Server operating systems. The only AMD graphics products with driver support for Windows Server operating systems are the AMD Professional Graphics products.​

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the driver from the Device manager and be sure to select the "Delete the driver software for this device" option".

Then reboot in Safe Mode and re-install the driver there. Be sure to install the drive using "Run as Administrator". If this fails, reboot normally and install the driver from a normal boot using "Run as Administrator"